# What is to the last as the rest to the first?

Tags: word-choice

When we speak about something being the `first` then everything after it is the `rest`. Well what I am looking for is a proper word that would refer to everything that's before the `last`.

To illustrate:

`[first|...rest]` vs `[???...|last]`

So can anyone help me with finding a word that would be to *last* the same as *rest* is to *first*?

Comment: I think it's also *rest* because rest means *all those not specifically called out*.  You might say, for example, "The last one to come in arrived at 9:00pm, the rest all got here before 8:30pm."

Comment: Does this work? - All but last!

Answer (score 1):

As @Jim says

> it's also rest because rest means all those *not specifically called out*.

You can however say in the first case, *successors* and in the second case, *predecessors* and their variants depending on context given by a [Thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/predecessor).

Comment: I also support "the rest." It is how you refer to what remains after what you specify. For example, "Every fifth man was given an application. The rest were dismissed."